# ¿Cuál es el máximo de campos permitidos en un Insert con un Store Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy revisando un proyecto de ejemplo utilizando MVVM y Store Procedures para el acceso a la BD en SQL Server. Quería saber si existe un máximo de campos que se pueden pasar a un Store Procedure desde C#.

En el ejemplo ponen 6 campos, pero si tengo una tabla con 30 ó 40 campos (factura, guía de remisión), considerando que la gran mayoría son ingresados por el usuario, ¿habrá una mejor forma de enviarlos a la tabla?

Esta es la línea de código del ejemplo.

```
dc.AddProduct(p.CategoryName, p.ModelNumber, p.ModelName, p.UnitCost, p.Description, ref newProductId);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Otra forma en que lo puedes hacer, es serializando los datos que desees enviar a la base de datos por medio de un XML, de esta forma solo estarías recibiendo un parámetro en tu *Stored Procedure*.

Por ejemplo, teniendo el siguiente XML:

```
<Producto>
    <ProductoId>1</ProductoId>
    <Descripcion>Descripción de algún producto</Descripcion>
    <FechaCreacion>2017-05-18</FechaCreacion>
</Producto>
```

Lo puedes leer en tu Stored Procedure de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddProduct (
    @contenidoXML XML
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
         Tabla.Columna.value('ProductoId[1]', 'INT')
        ,Tabla.Columna.value('Descripcion[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)')
        ,Tabla.Columna.value('FechaCreacion[1]', 'DATETIME')
    FROM @contenidoXML.nodes('//Producto') Tabla(Columna)
END
```

Al ejecutar el Stored Procedure solo tendrás esto:

```
dc.AddProduct(contenidoXML);
```

Si no tienes una clase con la definición de esos 30 campos, es posible crear el XML de forma dinámica.

Answer (score 5):

EL límite de Columnas en un insert es de 4096 columnas según [Éste](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server) Artículo.

> Columns per INSERT statement      4096

Creo que no necesitarías una "mejor forma" de enviarlos.

**EDIT:**

Complemento con la parte que dice

> Bytes in source text of a stored procedure        Lesser of batch size or
>   250 MB

y

> Parameters per stored procedure       2,100

**EDIT 2:**

Quizás Si, haya una mejor manera, enviando una representación XML de tu objeto al SP y deserializandolo para realizar el insert.

algo así:

```
<Params>
    <type ID="1"> 
        <value> 10 </value>
    </type>
    <type ID="2"> 
        <value> abc </value>
    </type>
</Params>
```

Deserialización:

```
    SELECT
        Type = TypeNode.value('@ID', 'int'),
        NodeValue = TypeNode.value('(value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM
        @XML.nodes('/Params/type') AS XTbl(TypeNode)
```

Pero en mi opinión, es mejor la forma "tradicional" de realizarlo.

Ésta info la saque de [Ésta Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13563017/6942330) en SO en inglés , en lo personal no logro entender mucho como trabaja pero quizás te ayude.

Comment: `Parameters per stored procedure  2,100` segun esa misma pagina :)

Comment: Entonces, tendría que tener un store procedure con los 30 campos y pasarlos todos entre parentesis, pensé que podría haber alguna forma mejor, gracias FederHico.

Comment: Hasta donde entiendo, esa es la manera

Comment: Ya edite de vuelta